# Why do timelocal and mktime fail to handle daylight savings correctly?

Tags: c, datetime, time, freebsd, darwin

I'm trying to understand how UNIX timelocal and mktime work. Supposedly they handle daylight savings time when you pass the proper value in the `struct tm` `tm_isdst` field.

I am testing a very specific moment in time. According to the timezone database for "America/New_York" the daylight savings shifted on Oct 30, 2005 at 01:00. Here's the output from `zdump -v America/New_York` which you can confirm on your own system. I'm only showing a subset of the data around the year 2005 (scroll right to see gmtoff values):

```
America/New_York  Sun Apr  3 06:59:59 2005 UT = Sun Apr  3 01:59:59 2005 EST isdst=0 gmtoff=-18000
America/New_York  Sun Apr  3 07:00:00 2005 UT = Sun Apr  3 03:00:00 2005 EDT isdst=1 gmtoff=-14400
America/New_York  Sun Oct 30 05:59:59 2005 UT = Sun Oct 30 01:59:59 2005 EDT isdst=1 gmtoff=-14400
America/New_York  Sun Oct 30 06:00:00 2005 UT = Sun Oct 30 01:00:00 2005 EST isdst=0 gmtoff=-18000
America/New_York  Sun Apr  2 06:59:59 2006 UT = Sun Apr  2 01:59:59 2006 EST isdst=0 gmtoff=-18000
America/New_York  Sun Apr  2 07:00:00 2006 UT = Sun Apr  2 03:00:00 2006 EDT isdst=1 gmtoff=-14400
```

To test this transition I am setting up a `struct tm` to contain 01:30 on that specific day. If I pass 0 for `tm_isdst` it should give me a gmtoffset of -18000. If I pass 1 and enable daylight savings, then gmtoffset should be -14400.

Here's the code I'm using to test on both Darwin/OSX and FreeBSD:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>


void print_tm(struct tm* tm) {
  printf("tm: sec [%d] min [%d] hour [%d] mday [%d] mon [%d] year [%d] wday [%d] yday [%d] isdst [%d] zone [%s] gmtoff [%ld]\n",
  tm->tm_sec,
  tm->tm_min,
  tm->tm_hour,
  tm->tm_mday,
  tm->tm_mon + 1,
  tm->tm_year,
  tm->tm_wday,
  tm->tm_yday + 1,
  tm->tm_isdst,
  tm->tm_zone,
  tm->tm_gmtoff);
  }

  struct tm* set_tm(int sec, int min, int hour, int mday, int mon, int year, int wday, int yday, int isdst, int gmtoff, char* zone) {
    struct tm* tm;

    tm = malloc(sizeof(struct tm));
    memset(tm, 0, sizeof(struct tm));

    tm->tm_sec = sec;
    tm->tm_min = min;
    tm->tm_hour = hour;
    tm->tm_mday = mday;
    tm->tm_mon = mon - 1;
    tm->tm_year = year;
    tm->tm_wday = wday;
    tm->tm_yday = yday - 1;
    tm->tm_isdst = isdst;
    tm->tm_zone = zone;
    tm->tm_gmtoff = gmtoff;

    return tm;
  }

  void test_timelocal(struct tm* tm, int isdst) {
    time_t seconds = -1;

    if(!setenv("TZ", "America/New_York", 1)) {
      printf("isdst is [%d]\n", isdst);
      tm->tm_isdst = isdst;

      tzset();
      seconds = timelocal(tm);

      localtime_r(&seconds, tm);
      print_tm(tm);
    } else {
      printf("setenv failed with [%s]\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    printf("\n");
  }

  void test_mktime(struct tm* tm, int isdst) {
    time_t seconds = -1;

    if(!setenv("TZ", "America/New_York", 1)) {
      printf("isdst is [%d]\n", isdst);
      tm->tm_isdst = isdst;

      tzset();
      seconds = mktime(tm);

      localtime_r(&seconds, tm);
      print_tm(tm);
    } else {
      printf("setenv failed with [%s]\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    printf("\n");
  }

int main(void) {
  struct tm* tm;

  printf("Test with timelocal\n");
  tm = set_tm(0, 30, 1, 30, 10, 2005, 0, 0, 0, 0, "");
  test_timelocal(tm, 0);

  tm = set_tm(0, 30, 1, 30, 10, 2005, 0, 0, 0, 0, "");
  test_timelocal(tm, 1);

  tm = set_tm(0, 30, 1, 30, 10, 2005, 0, 0, 0, 0, "");
  test_timelocal(tm, -1);


  printf("Test with mktime\n");
  tm = set_tm(0, 30, 1, 30, 10, 2005, 0, 0, 0, 0, "");
  test_mktime(tm, 0);

  tm = set_tm(0, 30, 1, 30, 10, 2005, 0, 0, 0, 0, "");
  test_mktime(tm, 1);

  tm = set_tm(0, 30, 1, 30, 10, 2005, 0, 0, 0, 0, "");
  test_mktime(tm, -1);

  return 0;
}
```

Running this on various OSes gives different results. On FreeBSD this code outputs (scroll right to see gmtoffset values):

```
Test with timelocal
isdst is [0]
tm: sec [0] min [30] hour [1] mday [30] mon [10] year [2005] wday [1] yday [303] isdst [1] zone [EDT] gmtoff [-14400]

isdst is [1]
tm: sec [0] min [30] hour [1] mday [30] mon [10] year [2005] wday [1] yday [303] isdst [1] zone [EDT] gmtoff [-14400]

isdst is [-1]
tm: sec [0] min [30] hour [1] mday [30] mon [10] year [2005] wday [1] yday [303] isdst [1] zone [EDT] gmtoff [-14400]

Test with mktime
isdst is [0]
tm: sec [0] min [30] hour [2] mday [30] mon [10] year [2005] wday [1] yday [303] isdst [1] zone [EDT] gmtoff [-14400]

isdst is [1]
tm: sec [0] min [30] hour [1] mday [30] mon [10] year [2005] wday [1] yday [303] isdst [1] zone [EDT] gmtoff [-14400]

isdst is [-1]
tm: sec [0] min [30] hour [1] mday [30] mon [10] year [2005] wday [1] yday [303] isdst [1] zone [EDT] gmtoff [-14400]
```

On darwin/OSX the exact same code produces this (scroll right to see gmtoffset values):

```
Test with timelocal
isdst is [0]
tm: sec [0] min [30] hour [1] mday [30] mon [10] year [2005] wday [1] yday [303] isdst [0] zone [EST] gmtoff [-18000]

isdst is [1]
tm: sec [0] min [30] hour [1] mday [30] mon [10] year [2005] wday [1] yday [303] isdst [0] zone [EST] gmtoff [-18000]

isdst is [-1]
tm: sec [0] min [30] hour [1] mday [30] mon [10] year [2005] wday [1] yday [303] isdst [0] zone [EST] gmtoff [-18000]

Test with mktime
isdst is [0]
tm: sec [0] min [30] hour [1] mday [30] mon [10] year [2005] wday [1] yday [303] isdst [0] zone [EST] gmtoff [-18000]

isdst is [1]
tm: sec [0] min [30] hour [0] mday [30] mon [10] year [2005] wday [1] yday [303] isdst [0] zone [EST] gmtoff [-18000]

isdst is [-1]
tm: sec [0] min [30] hour [1] mday [30] mon [10] year [2005] wday [1] yday [303] isdst [0] zone [EST] gmtoff [-18000]
```

To my eye it looks like BOTH of them get it WRONG. The `tm_isdst` field appears to have no effect on the `tm_gmtoff` field. The `tm_hour` output changes when using `mktime` but the offset is still wrong.

If you change the `tm_mday` to days earlier or days later the gmtoffset does not change at all which confuses me.

Am I doing something wrong or have I misinterpreted how these functions work?

Comment: DST changes at 02:00, not 01:00.

Comment: Months in `struct tm` go from `0` to `11`, so October is `9`, not `10`. You're printing the results for November 30, not October 30.

Comment: I solved it. The `tm->tm_year` field is based from 1900. So for 2005 I need to put (2005 - 1900) = 105 in that field. Then it works. As for @barmar's comment, the code adjusts for the 0-11 month counting already so that isn't the error. The `set_tm` function subtracts 1 from the month value.

Comment: That too. I just noticed that you were already adding/subtracting 1 for `tm_mon`.

Comment: You should post that as an answer. You're allowed to answer your own questions.

Comment: "Am I doing something wrong" --> Code should have check the return value of `mktime(tm); localtime_r()`.  Certainly that would have narrowed the problem quickly.

Comment: I removed that error checking in the interest of space (though I used plenty). None of these calls were throwing errors, so it would not have narrowed the problem space at all.

Answer (score -2):

UNIX time is very screwy. Turns out that my mistake has to do with the `tm_year` field in the `struct tm`. It is supposed to represent the number of years since 1900, so the value that goes in that field should be 105 and not 2005 (e.g. 2005 - 1900 = 105). This now yields the correct answer.

This definition of the struct can be found on [this very useful page.](http://www.catb.org/esr/time-programming/)

Comment: This was actually a very useful rubber duck session. I posted this question and then took the dogs for a walk. The answer came to me on the walk. :)

Comment: There's nothing "unix" about this. Unix time is integer seconds since the epoch in a unit that's called UTC but behaves more like UT1. What you're looking at, `struct tm` or "broken down time", is completely specified by ISO C and has nothing to do with unix.

Comment: That's a useless comment.

Comment: I don't see how so. It's a comment on the irrelevance/mispreresentation of the first sentence of your answer.

Comment: Sure, right. My pdp-11 used this same setup. Same for OS/390. My Amiga took the same approach. Ditto for MacOS prior to release 10. What's that? C ran on all of those platforms but didn't impose this screwiness? This stupid time setup is PRIMARILY from UNIX. This is an OS mistake and not a C language problem.

Comment: -1 for digging in on something you're completely wrong on. See *7.27.1 Components of time, ¶4*: "...int    tm_year;          //   years since 1900..."

Comment: -2 for being a useless pedant. I figured out the 1900 thing already; see answer.

Comment: I'm sorry. My ADD is getting the better of me. I'll leave you alone now.